# Why is the counter in Mutex is not in accordance with counter increment?

Tags: rust, synchronization, mutex, reference-counting

While I was practicing the code learn about the locking and unlocking the mutex in multiple threads. I run 10 different threads using for loop and initiated a mutex counter variable. The actual incrementing from for loop is fine but not in accordance with the mutex counter.

```
let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
let mut handles = vec![];

for _ in 0..10 {
    let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
    println!("Result: {:?}", counter);
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
        *num += 1;
    });
    handles.push(handle);
}
for handle in handles {
    handle.join().unwrap();
}
println!("Result: {}", *counter.lock().unwrap());
```

The output shows some absurd result in the mutex counter, I need to know why is that happening?

```
Result: Mutex { data: 0 } 
Result: Mutex { data: 0 }
Result: Mutex { data: 1 }
Result: Mutex { data: 2 }
Result: Mutex { data: 3 }
Result: Mutex { data: 4 }
Result: Mutex { data: 5 }
Result: Mutex { data: 6 }
Result: Mutex { data: 6 }
Result: Mutex { data: 8 }
Result: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You're printing the results in the main thread, which runs in parallel to the other threads, and thus doesn't give you deterministic results. If you instead print the results in the spawned threads after the mutex has been locked (to ensure only one thread sees the value at a time), you'll get more reasonable results:

```
let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
let mut handles = vec![];

for _ in 0..10 {
    let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
        *num += 1;
        println!("Result: {:?}", num);
    });
    handles.push(handle);
}
for handle in handles {
    handle.join().unwrap();
}
println!("Result: {}", *counter.lock().unwrap());
```

Output:

```
Result: 1
Result: 2
Result: 3
Result: 4
Result: 5
Result: 6
Result: 7
Result: 8
Result: 9
Result: 10
Result: 10
```

Comment: I would think even in this case you might get different orders (albeit each unique).

Comment: @chub500 its ok to print the num pointer value but I want to know why mutex counter value is not accordingly although num is just a pointer to that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. This is a good general primer to the motivation behind mutexes: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutex-lock-for-linux-thread-synchronization/

Comment: @chub500 It looks like it at first glance, but the first thing each thread does is lock the mutex, and the mutex remains locked by that thread until the closure returns, so the threads are guaranteed to run sequentially.

Comment: The threads may be scheduled and run in any order, but the first one to run is guaranteed to print 1, and the second one guaranteed to print 2, etc. If it were printing the loop iteration index it would be different.

Comment: I'm wrong - @trentcl is correct. His example makes the actual thread being run irrelevant and writing to a pipe (stdout) is also threadsafe so you should always see it ordered. Thanks @trentcl!